# Disappearance of <nav> bar when the position of <div> is set to relative

Tags: css, html, css-position, nav

When I am setting the position of `<div>` element to relative from the default (static), the `<nav>` bar disappears even the `<nav>` element appears before that `<div>` element. Here is what I did.

```html
<nav>
<a href="#Home">Nav 1</a>
<a href="#About">Nav 2</a>
<a href="">Nav 3</a>
<a href="">Nav 4</a>
<a href="">Nav 5</a>
</nav>

<div id="Home" class="divi">
<img src="software_update.jpg" style="width:100%; height:auto;">
<div id="imgtxt">Heading<br>heading 2</div>
<!--this div inside div is used to place text inside the image-->
</div>
```

and here is my CSS style sheet part for this-

```css
#Home{ position:relative;}
```

Can you please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: That alone doesn't change anything, what other CSS do you have?

Comment: create a jsfiddle or codepen!

Comment: It would be great if you'd add a Codepen or JsFiddle file - it'd be more interactive that way!

Comment: update the CSS or create a fiddle please

Comment: it will be impossible to answer you with that poor data but I strongly suggest learning how to debug css. Just right click -> inspect element then try to find you navbar in the element tree, and then use the "Computed" panel at the right to see the edimentions / position of your element, and use the "Styles" panel next to it to change / uncheck styles. In particular check the height, width, z-index and position . good luck - next time post a working example in codepen or jsfeedle

Answer (score 1):

Best guess, without better information, is that your nav is set to absolute or fixed. Then when you set the #home div to relative it is sliding up over top of it. To test try giving your #home div a negative z-index and/or some margin-top and see if your nav appears.